# Classification on time series items - choose not constant threshold

Tags: classification, predictive-modeling, time-series

I'm dealing with a classification problem on a time series {time: t, value: y(t)} where, for each time t,
my classification algorithm gives as ouput the probability that the y(t) belongs to class 0 or 1. It looks like a constant threshold, used for the whole time-series length, gives bad results. Instead, from a graphical inspection it looks that lowering the threshold in a very slow way would lead to better results.

The idea is, given the real value of the time series y(t), to lower the threshold in a real-time way after some false positives happen, and to increase it after some of false negative happen.

Does anything like this exist in the literature?

Thanks!